# Facebook Login Authentication:: How to save data after 1st Login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am going use facebook login Authentication for eCommerce website in PHP. I have gone through the facebook Docs, tutorial, blogs, youtube. But I am not able to fetch data or I don't know how to fetch data and save into database. I am using **Version 3** on which I am able to make simple login But how do I work on **Version 4**. This is 1st time I am working on facebook API even I have downloaded **PHP SDK** for both the Versions. Please help me to resolve my problem.

Regards
Vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get you going with FB PHP SDK:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     => YOUR-APP-ID,
    'secret'    => YOUR-APP-SECRET,
    ));

$this_user_facebook_id = $facebook->getUser(); // Get User ID

if($this_user_facebook_id > '0') // user logged in
    {
    try
        {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        //
        // check if this user exists in your database, if not - add him to your database
        //
        $LogoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
        }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e)
        {
        echo "Error! ".$e;
        }

    }   
else // user not logged in - publish a "login" link
    {
    $FBLoginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'user_status,user_about_me,share_item,email',
        'redirect_uri'  => YOUR-SITE-ADDRESS,
        ));
    }
```